# Can you travel within Portugal if your residency card is expired?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, portugal, ryanair

I am Syrian and I live (and study) in Lisbon, normally I fly between Porto and Lisbon and it is fine.

However, my residence card will expire this month, and I want to go to Porto from Lisbon on Ryanair *after the expiration date*.

Will they accept me to go into the plane with an expired residence card? ( i already applied for an extension but the extension will not happen before the flight). And I have an official appointment to extend the residence card.

My residence card is for students, the one that allows me to travel in Schengen area.

Comment: Does it have to be ryanair? They impose a whole bunch of additional restrictions that no other carrier does, significantly more than the law requires them, so they're problematic even in "normal" situations...

Comment: Why don't you simply take the train?

Comment: @gerrit in a hurry

Comment: @Gagravarr i called them, they said this is a domistic flight so i can fly with my passport

Comment: Did you calculate how much time you really save, including time to get to and from the airport on both sides?

Comment: @gerrit my meeting on 10:00 am, waking early is fine for me, specially that i  live so close the airport :). If I take the train, i will never arrive on time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I called Ryanair and they said that this kind of light is a domestic flight which needs either a valid *passport* or a *european national ID*. I do have a valid passport so It is Okay.

Comment: Indeed there is no way of looking at that flight where anyone could consider it anything other than a domestic flight.

Comment: @phoog maybe i didn't get you sorry, but don't you consider it a domestic flight ?

Comment: I do. My point is that there is no need for the word (or the concept of) "considered."  It *is* a domestic flight, by definition, because it is a flight entirely within a single country. By saying that Ryanair "considers" it to be a domestic flight, you imply potential controversy, as if you thought that someone else might not consider the flight to be domestic. I was challenging that implication.

Comment: @phoog oh yeah, you're right, thanks. Actually I knew from the beginning that there shouldn't be any problem with this kind of flight, but I'm not a European citizen, so I had to duple-check before.